# SaveSvc() IN WSDL of Genexus

Tags: postgresql, genexus

[image]

I am implementing WSDL with Genexus. 
When I insert data into the Table, I use **SaveSvc()** default procedure.
But I have a problem with this Procedure.
Look at the picture, please
It can do inserting only for **parent table** [Invoice].
**Child Table [Invoiceline] can't be inserted.**
So, I don't know how to solve this problem.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure that products with ProductId 1 and 2 exist? Please check what errors the method is returning.

Comment: ProductId 1 and 2 are already existed. The method isn't also returning any errors.Just cannot inserting child table.